# excel axis format in VB

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I have a sub that generates data, throws it into excel and then format's excel charts as well. This is done in VB, MS Visual Studio 2012. I am using Microsoft.Office.Interop in order to access excel workbook and spreadsheets - don't know if this is old and not the best way. With my charts y axis label I want the number to be percentage - can't find the way to do it.

Some code I have in my sub:

```
Dim ch3 as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ChartObject
Dim sh2 As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet
ch3 = sh.ChartObjects("chart 3")
ch3.chart.SetSourceData(sh2.Range("G3:I" & cCount + 2))
```

The following is the nearest I could find, but it does not work - error description is StandardAxis and ValueFormat is not declared:

```
ch3.Chart.Axis(StandardAxis.PrimaryY).ValueFormatting.Format = ValueFormat.Percentage
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This was done with Excel 2013 interop (dll version 15.0), C# syntax:

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

Axis yAxis = ch3.Chart.Axes(XlAxisType.xlValue);
yAxis.TickLabels.NumberFormat = "0%";
```

More on [format codes](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Number-format-codes-5026bbd6-04bc-48cd-bf33-80f18b4eae68).
[Answer source](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/1fa3e17f-40e4-4bc8-ad96-2782b500d088/problem-in-setting-axisticklabelsnumberformat-in-excel-chart-through-vsto)